QoS on Linux: tc doesn't see RTP traffic
I have a camera that creates RTSP traffic. I connected it to a Linux PC via Ethernet, configured the network and access. But when I tried to apply QoS rules, the tc statistics showed that too few bytes were sent.
After some research, I found that HTTP, SSH and RTSP (connection) traffic from the camera was displayed correctly in the statistics. However, tc seems to work differently with RTP traffic.
Video in VLC was playing, nft and tcpdump showed traffic. I tried using Debian 12, Ubuntu 24.04, Manjaro - it still didn't work. Imitating RTP with FFMPEG also did not bring success. This seems really weird and I didn't know what could cause the problem or what else to try.

Perhaps your QoS rules only applied to tcp, whereas RTP is over udp.

When I deleted all rules, it didn't change anything. There were no filters, and all traffic went from eth0 to a single class. Other qdiscs also didn't help.
tc qdisc del root dev $iface
tc qdisc add dev $iface root handle 1: htb default 1
tc class add dev $iface parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate 30mbit

I managed to solve my issue. The problem was not with RTP traffic, or any other type of traffic. When i used tc on eth0 interface (connected to camera), it showed only traffic to the camera, not from it. I don't know why this is so, but it seems really weird. Other utilities such as nft and tcpdump works correctly.
So the correct solution is to use external interface (such as wlan0). However, wlan0 is encrypted by Wireguard on my PC, so I can't really use it.
Anyway, if anyone having similar issues with tc, try to use other interfaces, if possible.
